# ReactJS - Event doesn't bind (Megaboilerplate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using React 15.1.0 and can't bind an event. I can't figured out what I'm doing wrong. This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';


class PatientProfile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
        this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
   }

    handleClick() {
        console.log('this is:');
    }

    render() {

        return (
          <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>off</button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PatientProfile;
```

I have searched online, tried samples on React official site and it didn't worked. Am I missing something in the installed packages?

Comment: I think the typical way of doing this is, in the constructor, to use `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`, and in the returned jsx section, to use `onClick={this.handleClick}`.

Comment: Your code is fine and will work without any issue.

Comment: @AndrewWillems I tried that way too and it doesn't work.

Comment: @dfsq I think the same but it didn't worked so I'm think there is some problem maybe with installed packages

Comment: Maybe. But this question doesn't have anything to be able to help you. The code is working, the rest noone knows but you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message in the console or what?

Comment: No errors. Just the events didn't binds. I'm using megaboilerplate as a framework. I'm a newbie to React

Comment: I just found out that I should build the bundle.js (npm run build), and then the events was binded

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I should build the bundle.js (npm run build), and then the events was binded